# How to integrate latest SDWebImage API in my Swift based project?

Tags: swift, xcode6, sdwebimage, ios8.1

I have used SDWebImage with Objective C and it worked great for me but now I am learning Swift and trying to integrate the latest version of the API but I am stucking at every step as API is in Objective C and there are no steps mentioned to use the API with Swift. 
I read the documents and created the bridge header file and included the required file like below:

```
#ifndef MyProject_Bridging_Header_h
#define MyProject_Bridging_Header_h

#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

#endif
```

I have added the frameworks as well and dragged the SDWebImage project within my app as explained [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-uiimageviewwebcache-category-with-uitableview)

I am really struggling in this. Please help! For reference I have added an image showing the error![image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948480/sdwebimage-crash-in-swift

Comment: better you use Haneke for caching images in swift https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

Comment: @Saurabh Prajapati: Have you used this? How is it?

Comment: Yes!almost before 2 month ago!

Comment: @Saurabh Prajapati Its not good as it is not maintaining the order of images in Table View and on scrolling while downloading, placement of image is wrong!

Comment: sorry but i've used it in collection view Where order of downloaded images doesn't matter!

Comment: it also have some others bugs too with new updates Xcode!

Comment: @Developer I just added your lines and it works correctly. `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` is on my bridging header. Also try to build your project in order to tell the compiler that you have included your headers. Try to remove the definitions you gave in bridging header, because I have nothing there.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati We were using Haneke until we found out that it periodically crashes the app when loading images. We raised an issue on Github but got no response for a few days. Now switching to SDWebImage.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit same...that issue still seems to be around.  I switched from Haneke to SDWebImage recently.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a code example that should work :

```
let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
    println(self)
}

let url = NSURL(string: "http://placehold.it/350x150")

self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, completed: block)
```

and in your bridging header file :

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

So your bridging header file should work, but sometimes I had trouble with the bridging header and in theses cases I just delete it, and add it again and everything works fine after.

Comment: I can use your solution but without the header and it still works well. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

The best option will be to drag and drop SDWebImage folder to project. Make sure 'copy items if needed' is ticked on.

Make a Obj C Bridging:File -> New -> Source -> Header File -> Name as AppName-Bridging-Header.

Add the following:

```
        #ifndef AppName_AppName_Bridging_Header_h
        #define AppName_AppName_Bridging_Header_h

        #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
        #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
        #endif

    or

 #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Note: Build Settings, in Swift Compiler - Code Generation, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header build setting under has a path to the bridging header file. - its like testSD/testSD-Bridging-Header.h or testSD-Bridging-Header.h (Open the Project folder and find the header file path)

Now try with this code:

```
let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
    println(self)
}

let url = NSURL(string: "http://arrow_upward.com/350x150")
self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, completed: block)
```

Suppose if you are using a UICollectionView to populate Cache imaging, try with this code.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = photoListCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("scoutimagecellidentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ScoutImageCell

        //Loading image from server using SDWebImage library
        let thumbImageUrl  =   NSURL(string: self.photoPropertyArray[indexPath.row] as String)

        //Image Fetching is done in background GCD thread        

SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadImageWithURL(thumbImageUrl, options: [],progress: nil, completed: {[weak self] (image, error, cached, finished, url) in

if let wSelf = self {

                //On Main Thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    cell.scoutimage.image = image
                    cell.photoloader.stopAnimating()
                }
            }
            })
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**swift 3.0 code**

> import SDWebImage

```
let url = URL.init(string:"https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/zelda/images/b/b1/Link_%28SSB_3DS_%26_Wii_U%29.png")
imagelogo.sd_setImage(with: url , placeholderImage: nil)
```