# Comprehending SDWebImage downloader

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

The docs aren't cutting it for me. Can someone give me sample code or an example of instantiating the SDWebImage downloader and using the downloadImageWithURL method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created a class for that, but here's how I use it:

```
- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL {
    _imageURL = imageURL;
    self.image = nil;
    [self.layer removeAllAnimations];

    if (!imageURL) {
        self.image = self.placeHolderImage;
        return;
    }

    __weak SDImageView *weakself = self;

    self.progressView.hidden = NO;

    SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock progressBlock =
    ^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
        if (expectedSize > 0) {
            float progress = receivedSize / (float)expectedSize;
            weakself.progressView.progress = MAX(MIN(1, progress), 0);
        }
    };

    SDWebImageCompletionWithFinishedBlock successBlock =
    ^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
        if (!image) image = self.placeHolderImage;

        weakself.imageOperation = nil;
        weakself.progressView.hidden = YES;
        weakself.progressView.progress = 0.f;

        if (cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeNone && !error) {
            [UIView transitionWithView:self
                              duration:1.f
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{
                                weakself.image = image;
                            } completion:nil];
        } else {
            weakself.image = image;
        }
    };

    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    self.imageOperation = [manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                                                options:SDWebImageRetryFailed
                                               progress:progressBlock
                                              completed:successBlock];
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This is what I wanted to see.

Comment: what if i want to download image from web and store it in file manager for further use?

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do? Give us more details.

Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27617962/846780

Github: https://github.com/ZuYuanZhou/testSD

Comment: how can i upload images with SDImages? can i have only options for uploading image is AFNetworking?

Comment: @iosdeveloper SDWebImage is an "Asynchronous image downloader with cache support as a UIImageView category". I doesn't upload images. To upload image you can use many other libs (such as AFNetworking).